# How to iterate over object with a component in redux

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I want to map over an object and pass down values as props

Im working on a redux project, i originally had an array of object so it was easier to iterate over them , but ive been asked to convert my initial state to a js object but i am having a tough time refactoring it

```
// Original State
lists = [
  {
    id: 0,
    title: "List1",
    cards: [
      {
        id: 0,
        title: "card1",
        user: "ali"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "List2",
    cards: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "card1",
        user: "ahmed"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "card2",
        user: "khalid"
      }
    ]
  }
];

// This is where I map over the card and send the values as props
cards.map(card => (
  <TodoCard
    key={card.id}
    title={card.title}
    listId={listId}
    cardId={card.id}
    user={card.user}
  />
));
```

The code is working fine, but how do i iterate over if the array is converted to a js object given below

```
lists = [
  {
    id: 0,
    title: "List1",
    cards: {
      cardDetail: {
        id: 0,
        title: "card1",
        user: "ali"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "List2",
    cards: {
      cardDetail: [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: "card1",
          user: "ahmed"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: "card2",
          user: "khalid"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
];
```

Comment: The second code example with the JS object is invalid syntax. You need property names for the nested objects. Aside from that, if you do have a proper JS object, you can iterate over the values using [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

Comment: can you provide me with an example of how the second example should look like ... i didnt quiet understand @PatrickHund

Comment: Ertan beat me to it 

Comment: Haha ... its ok ... is my question more sensible now ?

Comment:  almost there, but the property names need to be different, you can't use listDetails and cardDetails multiple times. Anyway, I understand the problem, and my tip for you is still to use Object.values

Answer (score 0):

You just can't do it like that.
You either need to use

```
list = [{object}, {object}];
//or
list = {myList: [{object}, {object}]}
```

You can't just write

```
list = {{object}, {object}}
```

since its invalid syntax.

Take a look at what are and how you can use objects and arrays

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
  cards:{ 
          cardDetail:
         {
          id:1,
          title:"card1",
          user:"ahmed"
         },
         {
          id:2,
          title:"card2",
          user:"khalid"
         }
        }
  }
```

You can iterate using `Object.keys()` which would give all the key and then do `forEach`.

```
Object.keys(cards).forEach((key,index) => {
    // key: the name of the object key....    cardDetail here
    // index: the ordinal position of the key within the object 
// value : cards[key]... value of the object.


});
```

You will also need to do looping on `value : cards[key]` as it has multiple objects which seems inefficient so better would be to design the data object if possible